# Cannot read property 'username' of undefined for Angular Post Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

From a tutorial I set up my app to post to my endpoint on the click of a button in angularjs. In the tutorial it works, but for me it doesn't work.

`if (!(req.body.username === 'john.doe' && req.body.password === 'foobar')) {`
Is the problem line

serverapp.js

```
// LOAD ---- ---- ---- ----
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var HTTPS_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3111;
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var epilogue = require('epilogue');
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();
var morgan = require('morgan'); // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)


var expressJwt = require('express-jwt'); //https://npmjs.org/package/express-jwt
var secret = 'this is the secret secret secret 12356';
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');  //https://npmjs.org/package/node-jsonwebtoken


// We are going to protect /api routes with JWT
app.use('/api', expressJwt({
    secret: secret
}));


app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));


// if there's ever an unauth error, we redirect them
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.constructor.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized :(');
    }
});


app.post('/authenticate', function (req, res) {
  //TODO validate req.body.username and req.body.password
  //if is invalid, return 401
  if (!(req.body.username === 'john.doe' && req.body.password === 'foobar')) {
    res.status(401).send('Wrong user or password');
    return;
  }

  var profile = {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe',
    email: 'john@doe.com',
    id: 123
  };

  // We are sending the profile inside the token
  var token = jwt.sign(profile, secret, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });

  res.json({ token: token });
});


// ...MODELS, relations, rest endpoints and all that crap withheld from stack overflow

        app.get('/api/restricted', function(req, res) {
            console.log('user ' + req.body.username + ' is calling /api/restricted');
            res.json({
                name: 'foo'
            });
        });
```

clientapp.js

```
myApp.controller('userController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.user = {username: 'thisshouldbeempty', password: 'thisshouldbeempty'};
  $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
  $scope.welcome = '';
  $scope.message = '';

  $scope.loginUser = function () {

    $http
      .post('/authenticate', $scope.user)

      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
        $scope.isAuthenticated = true;
        var encodedProfile = data.token.split('.')[1];
        var profile = JSON.parse(url_base64_decode(encodedProfile));
        $scope.welcome = 'Welcome ' + profile.first_name + ' ' + profile.last_name;
      })
// etc....
```

html partial, login is invoked via button press

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light"   ng-click="loginUser()">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `bodyParser` to access req.body:

```
var app = require('express')();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer'); // v1.0.5
var upload = multer(); // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: Thanks but yes I did I just didn't want to add all the includes in the code snippet to make my post super long

Comment: @NatuMyers The error you get is that req.body is undefined . So I think the issue in the serverapp, not in client app. Can you provide "// ALL INCLUDES...." code?

Comment: I did not try running your code, @NatuMyers. As such, I am not aware of the exact error you got. user1280859 might be right.

Comment: @NatuMyers Ok, yes. You didn't use bodyParser but only require it. See my code snippet (6,7 lines)

Comment: Just added in the includes. I found out that If i move `
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
            extended: true
        })); app.use(bodyParser.json());
` up and it tells me nothing unless I enter in john.doe and foobar, then it says jwt.sign is not a function

Comment: Ok I think I'm good! it's supposed to do that, now i just have to sign jwt properly! thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment in the code:

`//TODO validate req.body.username and req.body.password`

The code is lacking validation of input. You are getting the error `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined for Angular Post Request` because 'username' is undefined.

You need to check that the user has provided the inputs required for the post request, i.e.

```
if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password)
    return; // should probably return some sort of error code
```

Elaboration: `'should probably return some sort of error code'`: send a JSON response with error code 404 and a relevant error message such as "No username specified." and "No password specified."

e.g.

```
if(!req.body.username) {
    res.status(404).send('No username specified');
    return;
}

if(!req.body.password) {
    res.status(404).send('No password specified');
    return;
}
```

Comment: @Natu Myers, you should also check your router to make sure that there are no spelling mistakes, i.e. the parameters are correctly named 'username' and 'password' respectively.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't solve my problem (same error) but it is helpful. For some reason angular just isn't assigning anything to username

Comment: @Natu Myers, despite having provided an input for the username, you are getting `undefined`? Well, then, can I see your router code snippet?